# What are possible trekking routes in the Atacama region in Chile in mid April?

Tags: trekking, weather, deserts

I would like to visit northern Chile and particularly the [Atacama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atacama_Desert) region. The goal would be to trek in the area, during about 10-12 days. It can be one long route or several shorter ones.

What routes are accessible between mid-April and beginning of March? Any restriction due to the weather conditions?

Comment: Being as this particular question isn't getting much love, maybe you could get some better help at http://travel.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Hiking in Northern Chile is difficult because it is a high desert with practically no water.

A possible alternative is to rent a good 4x4 truck in Arica, fill it up with water, food, and fuel for several days and explore the area around Putre (on the border with Peru and Bolivia). If you go solo, bring extra spare tires and a satellite phone (for emergencies) - this is very very remote country.

The landscapes are amazing: cactus forests, geisers, volcanoes, high alti-planos, etc.

We did exactly this back in 2015; for photos see https://www.flickr.com/photos/brijsman/albums/72157661317255934

Comment: Wow, beautiful photos. Looks like a fantastic place to visit.